# How to query data from ADO.NET Entity Model in Model of asp.net mvc c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am a new to asp.net mvc c#, Now I created an ADO.NET Entity Model , and retrieved all the table in my database to put in it. Now I have create a View in my project, and I want to take the data from the ADO.net entity to show in my view as the table or something else.

Could anyone show me, how can I query data from ADO.net entity in my model of asp.net mvc?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are new to mvc then i think that the great starting point would be to download projects   http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/ and http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/ and go from there. you will definitely get your answer from there.also see this to get the idea

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/movie-database/create-a-movie-database-application-in-15-minutes-with-asp-net-mvc-cs